# Host of docker container gets unresponsive - how to make host independent from container?

Tags: docker

How can I prevent that a docker host gets unresponsive if the docker container is under high load?

My docker host server gets unresponsive at certain times, and only a restart helps. We assume this happens when the docker container performs CPU intensive tasks. Whenever this happens, I cannot login to the docker host.
In case I am logged in already, I usually cannot use the shell; sometimes I can use the shell with an about 10 minutes delay for characters to be typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed no limit on a container per default, but there is a large amount of flags allowing you to control a container behaviour at run time.

> By default, a container has no resource constraints and can use as much of a given resource as the host’s kernel scheduler allows. Docker provides ways to control how much memory, or CPU a container can use, setting runtime configuration flags of the `docker run` command. This section provides details on when you should set such limits and the possible implications of setting them.

Here is a **totally not exhaustive** example using some of those flags

```
docker run -it --cpus="1.5" --memory="1g" ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Just make sure your limits are set to something sensible allowing your host machine to still do what it is supposed to do (run the daemon or other tasks).

A comprehensive list of all those flags allowing you to control resources is accessible via https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/

Comment: for docker-compose it would be something like `mem_limit: 300m` in the docker-compose.yaml file.

Comment: For estimating the right amount of memory, `docker stats -all` can help.